# Access-Control-Allow-Origin syntax

Tags: php, ajax, http, cross-domain, cors

I want allow Cross-origin resource sharing from all the *sub-domain of from.example.com*.
So I added Cross-origin resource sharing header as given below to a page in *subdomain1.to.example.com*.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.from.example.com');
```

And I tried to access the page form *subdomain1.from.example.com* using ajax.
I didn't get the response. So I just changed the above header as given below.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://subdomain1.from.example.com');
```

It works well for the *subdomain1.from.example.com* only.

What was the issue with first header?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744278/access-control-allow-origin-syntax

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wildcards are not allowed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It has to be an exact match. You can either allow all domains by setting the value to `*`, or conditionally echo the value of the `Origin` request header if it matches one of your allowed domains.

Note that the [Origin spec allows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1) for multiple origins separated by a space. However I am not sure if this works with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It may be worth a try.