# Read URL Content in javascript using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to read the content of a URL in javascript. The URL is not on my domain so I need a middle layer that can access cross domain.
I tried to use a PHP function to read the URL and return the result to javascript using jquery but it didn't work.

Here is my trial:

I created a php file named "phpjs_test.php"

```
<?php
function get_data(){
  $url='http://asmary.dreameg.com/texttable.txt';
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  $content = htmlspecialchars($content);
  curl_close($ch);
  $content = nl2br($content);
  return $content;
}
?>
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //httpQuery("http://asmary.dreameg.com/texttable.txt");
            getOutput();
        });

        function getRequest() {
            var req = false;
            try {
                // most browsers
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                // IE
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // try an older version
                    try {
                        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return req;
        }

        function getOutput() {
            var ajax = getRequest();
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }
            };
            ajax.open("GET", "phpjs_test.php", true);
            ajax.send(null);
        }
```

I'm completely new to PHP so I don't know even the PHP function is correct or not.

Comment: "It didn't work" isn't a very useful diagnostic.

Comment: You need to use `echo`, not `return`, for AJAX to pick up the response

Comment: but he can call it like echo get_data(); and it should work fine.

Comment: @GordonM well, it didn't return the content of the url as it should do.

Comment: @DamienPirsy used echo instead of return but it make no difference.

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly Well say that then!  Also say what you were expecting it to return, and what it actually did return instead, along with any errors and warnings that got logged in the PHP and/or javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should just use jQuery ajax methods instead of creating XMLHTTPRequest you don't have to bother with adding more code for IE plus you're already loading the jQuery library. Also if you set the header to Allow-Origin-Access in your PHP file and specify the other domain you're requesting from then you can make an AJAX request and get the response otherwise it will return nothing or in your dev tools network tab it will show a 403 - Forbidden.

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744278/access-control-allow-origin-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP file to:

```
<?php
$url='http://asmary.dreameg.com/texttable.txt';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$content = explode('~',$content);

foreach($content as $c)
{
    $records[] = explode('|',$c);
}
$content = json_encode($records);
echo $content;
?>
```

Javascript will receive a json array like this

```
[["1","name1","10","city1"],["2","name2","20","city2"],["3","name3","30","city3"],["4","name4","40","city4"],["5","name5","50","city5"],["6","name6","60","city6"],["7","name7","7","city7"],["8","name8","80","city8"],["9","name9","90","city9"],["10","name10","100","city10"],["11","name11","11","city11"],["12","name12","12","city12"],["13","name13","13","city13"],["14","name14","14","city14"],["15","name15","15","city15"],["16","name16","16","city16"],["17","name17","17","city17"],["18","name18","18","city18"],["19","name19","19","city19"],["20","name20","20","city20"],[""]]
```

Comment: You should also encode the file texttable.txt to ANSI to avoid problems (save it with a plain text editor like notepad)

Comment: You need to save the PHP file with a .php extention

Comment: It is a php file. I created a file and changed the extension to .php.

Comment: What's the URL to the php file?

Comment: I didn't uploaded the website online yet. It's content is just as u written

Comment: You need a webserver to run PHP. HTML and javascript do not need a webserver. Try uploading it to test it :)